# vscode eslint not ignoring directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-eslint

Despite clearly indicating in esignore that I want to ignore everything inside lib directory, vscode is saying 9 problems found in that minimized file.

If I run eslint inside foldera in command line everything is fine

using this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

My directory structure:

```
foldera/
    .eslintrc
    .eslintignore
    src/
        file.js
    lib/
        wantoignore.min.js
folderb/
    morefiles.js
    .eslintrc
    .eslintignore
```

**.eslintrc file**

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017,
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-console": "off"
    }
}
```

**.eslintignore**

```
lib/*
```

workspace settings:

```
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
      "./client", "./server"
   ]
```

Comment: not sure if this will help anyone else, but my fix was simply to restart VSCode

Comment: I am having the same problem and it is very annoying. Has there been any progress on that problem? – I filed and issue at the github repo. (BTW: restarting didn't help)

Comment: after updates it stopped doing that

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem following the [official doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint#settings-options) here.

Basically you need to add the following content to the vscode workspace settings (usually located in your project's `root/.vscode/settings.json`), so that vscode knows which configs to honor when you're working on a specific script file:

```
{
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [ "./reactApp" ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solutions is:

**Source map**

```
root/.vscode/settings.json
```

**Script**

```
    {  
      "eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, figured out need to set workingDirectory to nested folder:

```
module
  lib
    src
      index.ts
    .eslintrc.js
    .eslintignore
```

VSCode setting should be:

```
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [ "./module/lib" ]
```

And not

```
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [ "./module" ]
```