# Stop vs code formatter from formatting .env file

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm using prettier & eslint on vs code and i would like to stop it from formatting my .env file on save.

It adds semi-colons to the end of every variable, which is obviously not good.

Answer (score 2):

Under the project folder, create a subfolder `.vscode`, then touch a `settings.json` file under the subfolder, paste the following config into the `setting.json`. It would stop auto-formatting on env file.

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "[dotenv]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to configure ESlint and Prettier separately.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422058/vscode-eslint-not-ignoring-directory) answers for instructions on how to configure ESLint, and [this](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) one for instructions on how to force Prettier to ignore files.

Answer (score 0):

Add to a `.prettierignore` `.env*`.
That did the trick for me.